# Remove substring with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove substring from this string (of course, the original is longer)

> case 'meter': xy=1; //meter square break; case 'decimeter_square':
>    xy=1E2; //decimeter square break; case 'centimeter_square': xy=1E4;
>   //centimeter square break; case 'milimeter_square': xy=1E6;

The text is in one single line and I need the output this like this:

```
case 'meter': xy=1; break; case 'decimeter_square': xy=1E2; break;
case 'centimeter_square': xy=1E4; break; case 'milimeter_square':
xy=1E6;
```

So I need to remove everything after the **'//'** and before **'break'**

Thanks everybody for advice

Comment: Use 4 spaces to format code code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace regex pattern `//.*?break;` with `//break;`